# how to print delay sequence in spring retry

Tags: java, spring, sequence, spring-retry, retry-logic

I know to print number of counts inside retryable method. how to print delay sequence inside retryable method

```
@Retryable( value = SQLException.class, 
      maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
void testMethod(String abc) throws SQLException{
log.info("Retry Number : {} and delay: ",RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount());
};
```

expected output:
Retry Number: 1 delay : 1000
Retry Number: 2 delay : 1000
Retry Number: 3 delay : 1000

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to retrieve the delay.